# Первый код забирает свойства со второго (размер текста)

Tags: javascript

Возможно вам будет сложно понять. Я не программист, я использую сервис, позволяющий создавать сайт практически без кода.

На самом легком примере скажу в чем проблема: когда я вставляю два таких кода (мне нужны две таких анимации текста на разных позициях сайта) и в одном делаю размер текста 15px, а в другом 40px - при просмотре в браузере размер текста не отличается. Хотя в коде прописано разное значение. То есть один текст (код анимации текста) берет свойства со второго.

Я оставлю код здесь, но возможно, чтобы лучше понять, вам понадобится практический пример: http://text-test-75fece.webflow.io/ (Этот сайт показывает, что свойства одинаковы (в этом случае - размер текста) в независимости от того, что размер текста в "коде страницы" имеет разное значение для каждого предложения.

Я просто не понимаю в чем причина. Мне нужна такая анимация и для заголовка, подзаголовка и других форм текста. Пожалуйста, помогите в решении этого вопроса

```js
// jshint esnext: true

const ANIM_SELECTOR = 'p:nth-child(even)', // '.text'
  ANIM_CHARSBYSTEP = 1, // одинаковых симв. за шаг (int, >=0)
  ANIM_DELAYMS = 30; // задержка в мс(int, >=0)

var d = document,
  de = d.documentElement,
  textEls;

d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let init = new Promise(resolve => {
    textEls = d.querySelectorAll(ANIM_SELECTOR);
    for (let el of textEls) {
      spanner(el);
      el.classList.add('animated');
    }
    resolve();
  });
  init.then(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    window.addEventListener('load', onScroll);
  });
});

function onScroll(e) {
  let bcr;
  for (let el of textEls) {
    bcr = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    // если элемент вне вьюпорта - сбрасываем и пропускаем его
    if ((bcr.top > de.clientHeight) || (bcr.bottom < 0)) {
      clearState(el);
      continue;
    }
    // если анимация не выполняется, то запускаем
    if (!el.dataset.anim) {
      el.dataset.anim = true;
      animateFrames(el);
    }
  }
}

function spanner(el) {
  let chars = el.textContent.split(' '),
    html = '';
  chars.forEach(chr => html += `<span>${chr}</span> `);
  el.innerHTML = html;
}

function clearState(el) {
  if (!el.dataset.anim)
    return;
  el.dataset.anim = '';
  let sp, cl;
  for (sp of el.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
    cl = sp.classList; // как ни странно, это быстрее
    while (cl.length) // чем простое присвоение
      cl.remove(cl[0]); // строкой: sp.className=''
  }
}

function animateFrames(el, charsByStep = ANIM_CHARSBYSTEP, delayMs = ANIM_DELAYMS) {
  let spans = sortedSpans(el),
    start = 0,
    chars, sp, len, more; // это выиграет ~10% производительности
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);

  function anim(time) {
    if (time - start >= delayMs) {
      chars = charsByStep;
      do {
        if (!(sp = spans.shift()) || !el.dataset.anim)
          return;
        sp.classList.add('show');
        len = spans.length;
        more = !!len && (spans[0].textContent < 'a');
        if (!more && len && (sp.textContent !== spans[0].textContent))
          chars--;
      } while (more || (chars > 0));
      start = time;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
}

function sortedSpans(el) {
  let spans = Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('span'));
  return spans.sort((s1, s2) => s1.textContent.localeCompare(s2.textContent));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  font: 300 18px 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

p {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.animated span {
  color: transparent;
  transition: all 0s;
  will-change: color;
  /* пытаемся вынудить браузер задействовать GPU */
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.animated span.show {
  color: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font: 300 30px 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

p {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.animated span {
  color: transparent;
  transition: all 0s;
  will-change: color;
  /* пытаемся вынудить браузер задействовать GPU */
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.animated span.show {
  color: inherit;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<p>Great results don’t just happen. We design and build your business for tomorrow.</p>
<p>Great results don’t just happen. We design and build your business for tomorrow.</p>
```

Comment: Можно узнать, а где в примере 40px? Из-за этого не видна проблемы. Поправьте пример так, чтобы можно было увидеть проблему.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin я подправил, спасибо. Сейчас вы можете полноценно взглянуть на проблему. Посмотрите на различие в размере текста. Они разные.

Comment: @Bogdan, если вместо редактирования продолжишь удалять и добавлять одни и те же вопросы, система может ограничить тебя в создании новых вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS расшифровывается как **Cascading** StyleSheet.

Это означает, что описанные правила накладываются друг на друга и дополняют/переписывают предыдущие правила.

Например:

```
body {
  background: #000;
  font: 300 18px 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font: 300 30px 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

В этом случае применится последнее описание и размер шрифта будет `30px`.

Чтобы были разные размеры, то нужно разделять элементы, к которым применяется конкретный стиль.

Например, можно использовать отдельные классы:

```
.paragraph { font-size: 18px; }
.heading { font-size: 30px; }
```

И назначить их соответствующим элементам:

```js
// jshint esnext: true

const ANIM_SELECTOR = 'p', // '.text'
  ANIM_CHARSBYSTEP = 1, // одинаковых симв. за шаг (int, >=0)
  ANIM_DELAYMS = 30; // задержка в мс(int, >=0)

var d = document,
  de = d.documentElement,
  textEls;

d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let init = new Promise(resolve => {
    textEls = d.querySelectorAll(ANIM_SELECTOR);
    for (let el of textEls) {
      spanner(el);
      el.classList.add('animated');
    }
    resolve();
  });
  init.then(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    window.addEventListener('load', onScroll);
  });
});

function onScroll(e) {
  let bcr;
  for (let el of textEls) {
    bcr = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    // если элемент вне вьюпорта - сбрасываем и пропускаем его
    if ((bcr.top > de.clientHeight) || (bcr.bottom < 0)) {
      clearState(el);
      continue;
    }
    // если анимация не выполняется, то запускаем
    if (!el.dataset.anim) {
      el.dataset.anim = true;
      animateFrames(el);
    }
  }
}

function spanner(el) {
  let chars = el.textContent.split(' '),
    html = '';
  chars.forEach(chr => html += `<span>${chr}</span> `);
  el.innerHTML = html;
}

function clearState(el) {
  if (!el.dataset.anim)
    return;
  el.dataset.anim = '';
  let sp, cl;
  for (sp of el.getElementsByTagName('span')) {
    cl = sp.classList; // как ни странно, это быстрее
    while (cl.length) // чем простое присвоение
      cl.remove(cl[0]); // строкой: sp.className=''
  }
}

function animateFrames(el, charsByStep = ANIM_CHARSBYSTEP, delayMs = ANIM_DELAYMS) {
  let spans = sortedSpans(el),
    start = 0,
    chars, sp, len, more; // это выиграет ~10% производительности
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);

  function anim(time) {
    if (time - start >= delayMs) {
      chars = charsByStep;
      do {
        if (!(sp = spans.shift()) || !el.dataset.anim)
          return;
        sp.classList.add('show');
        len = spans.length;
        more = !!len && (spans[0].textContent < 'a');
        if (!more && len && (sp.textContent !== spans[0].textContent))
          chars--;
      } while (more || (chars > 0));
      start = time;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
}

function sortedSpans(el) {
  let spans = Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('span'));
  return spans.sort((s1, s2) => s1.textContent.localeCompare(s2.textContent));
}
```

```css
p {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.paragraph {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.animated span {
  color: transparent;
}

.animated span.show {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="paragraph">Great results don’t just happen. We design and build your business for tomorrow.</p>
<p class="heading">Great results don’t just happen. We design and build your business for tomorrow.</p>
```

Comment: И все же проблема не решена полностью. Если мне необходимо изменить область ширины в которой текст будет находиться - меняется ширина всех предложений. Аналогично размеру. Скорее всего такая же проблему будет с положением на странице. Есть ли выход из этих ситуаций?

Comment: @Bogdan, в текущем коде, скорость одинаковая для всех элементов.

Comment: @Bogdan, я не совсем понимаю, что ты имеешь ввиду под областью ширины. Но как сказано в ответе - стиль ты можешь применять к конкретному элементу, и в нем описывать только то, что относится к нему.

Comment: все хорошо. Это обычное незнание - мне удалось решить возникшую проблему. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Потревожу вас вновь, но скажите, а если я хочу поменять шрифт отдельно для каждого предложения? С помощью класса не получается

Comment: @Bogdan, пока единственное решение - каждое предложение обернуть в свой элемент